# Where can I find information for the JVM binary format in order to create my own JVM

Tags: java, jvm, implementation

Is there any documentation on how the JVM runs/interprets Java's binary format? I would like to make my own implementation of the JVM, but I'm unsure where to start.

Comment: Yes, it's the [JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/).

Comment: Oh that exists. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you download and build the OpenJDK first so you understand what it does before trying to create your own.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ~600 page tome on everything about the JVM called the *Java Virtual Machine specification*. [[Find here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf)]

Chapter 4 describes the *class* file format of the Java Virtual Machine and should give you enough information to get started.

Comment: Oh a PDF version, that's helpful.